# Xdsoft datetime - set a minimum, starting date

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using Xdsoft datetime picker. I want the user to select a date, but starting from today's date with an offset of 3 days.

For example today is 9/10/2015 the datetimepicker should start with a date of 13/10/2015 and so one.

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    yearOffset:222,
    lang:'ch',
    timepicker:false,
    format:'d/m/Y',
    formatDate:'Y/m/d',
    minDate:'-1970/01/02', // yesterday is minimum date
    maxDate:'+1970/01/02' // and tommorow is maximum date calendar
});
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/jhvsjfmr/

**HTML:**

```
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text"  value="">
```

**JS:**

```
function getDate()
{    
    var today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate()-3);
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) dd='0'+dd
    if(mm<10) mm='0'+mm
    today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

    return today;   
}

$('#datetimepicker').val(getDate())

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'m/d/Y'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

     'use strict';       

        var DVl = new Date();
        DVl.setDate(DVl.getDate() - 2);

        var DVlD = DVl.getDate();
        var DVlM = DVl.getMonth()+1;

        if(DVlD < 10){

            DVlD = '0'+ DVlD;
        }

        if(DVlM < 10){

            DVlM = '0'+ DVlM;
        }

       var FnlD = DVl.getFullYear() +'-'+ DVlM +'-'+ DVlD;       

       jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({

          format:'d-m-Y ',

          timepicker : false, 

          minDate: FnlD
      });
  });
```

You can set the minDate value directly like minDate : '04-06-2019'. If you want dynamic date changes you could follow the above code.